# Create and add a button from WebMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, webmethod

I make a webmethod call and get an answer from the server if the current user can/can't print a document.

If the user can print, I want to display a print button. Otherwise not.

Is there a way to add a print button to an existing "div" from a web method?

Comment: No, you can't add a button in the client DOM using a WebMethod but it can be done in client side script (same that called WebMethod) according to its response.

Comment: please, add your code snippet to get better answer

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to do it from client-side for security reasons. The client can fake the server result and then get the print button although he is not allowed to print.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this(sorry, not tested)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/yourPage.aspx/YourWebMethod",
  data: "{yourParameterName:'" + yourparamvalue + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
      async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element.setAttribute("value", "invert");
    element.setAttribute("name", "button3");
    element.setAttribute("onclick", "foo()");
    var targetElement = document.getElemanById('yourdivid');
    targetElement.appendChild(element);

  },
  error: function () { alert('/yourPage.aspx/YourWebMethod'); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to do it from client-side for security reasons. The client can fake the server result and then get the print button although he is not allowed to print.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add from web method, simply add button where ever you want to show, make sure it is hidden by default. check the value return from page method and show/hide button based on value.

```
PageMethods.CheckPermission(function (flag) {
    if (flag == "1")
        $("#btnPrint").show();
    else 
        $("#btnPrint").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to do it from client-side for security reasons. The client can fake the server result and then get the print button although he is not allowed to print.

Comment: Is print a server side action or client side `document.print`?

Comment: window.print() - client side